# How to sum rows with a timepoint and a duration criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I got two tables. One with 36 columns representing three years and a second table with three columns  a number a start month and a duration in months. In the second table I got different rows, for e.g. rent of a car a house and so on. In my first table I want the sum of costs of every entry in the second table regarding a specific month. As long as I use a startmonth and a endmonth it is easy archived with the "sumifs" function. But when I want to use a startmonth and a duration (e.g. month 5 is start and the duration is 11 months) I do not now a way how to refer to the startmonth in the sumifs function.

**UPDATE**

```
The table looks like

Cost per month | TimeStart | Duration in Month
---------------+-----------+-------------------
1000           | Jan 15    | 5
---------------+-----------+-------------------
750            | March 15  | 3
...and so on
```

and the second Table looks like

```
Month|Jan |Feb |March|April|Jun |Jul |Aug | .....
-----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+------
Cost |1000|1000|1750 |1750 |1750|750 |750 | .....
```

I want to generate the second table from the first

Comment: Could you add either a mockup of your data or a screen shot?  Not being familiar with your data structure, what the values look like, and the operations you want to perform, the description is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin,

Since you said that you have no problem getting your information using startmonth and endmonth then how about you derive the endmonth using the following formula using the startmonth value and the duration

=EDATE(A2,B2)

...where A2 has the startdate and B2 has the duration in months.

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

Since you said that you have no problem getting your information using startmonth and endmonth then how about you derive the endmonth using the following formula using the startmonth value and the duration.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2,DAY(A2))
```

...where A2 has the startdate and B2 has the duration in months.